# RewriteRule in JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, jboss, jboss7.x

I successfuly *played* with rewrite rules in rewrite.properties.

Now, i would like to rewrite url like this:

```
 https://localhost:8443/test/customer1/login.xhtml
```

to

```
 https://localhost:8443/test/login.xhtml?customer=customer1
```

I thus use the following rewrite rule but it doesn't work.

```
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$/login\.xhtml /login.xhtml?customer=$1
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. The page is not found. Has anybody an idea?

And do you know how i could log or see the resulting url after the rewriting?

Comment: By the way, what web framework do you use? Most have some kind of rewriting built in - JSF 2, Wicket, to name few.

Answer (score 3):

Could you post your .properties file?

Here's the JBoss Web [docs for rewrite.properties](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/rewrite.html) (for the reference of others).

And if you don't come to a solution with that, try [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).

But looking closer at your regexp, it seems you need to study that matter a bit more.
I would recommend not using `customer1` `but customer/1` - without a slashs it's harder to split in general case. Anyway:

```
RewriteRule ^/customer([0-9]+)/login\.xhtml /login.xhtml?customer=$1
```

Regarding logging, seems that the valve uses this code to log:

```
295                   if (container.getLogger().isDebugEnabled()) {
296                       container.getLogger().debug("Rewrote " + test + " as " + newtest
297                               + " with rule pattern " + rules[i].getPatternString());
```

So you'd probably get that message by setting whole `org.jboss.web` or `org.apache.catalina` to DEBUG. Then check `standalone/log/server.log`.

**Update:** I thought the quester wanted to parse "customer1" to "customer=1". It turned out he just wants to move the path segment...

So, I'd try:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/login\.xhtml /login.xhtml?customer=$1
```

which means, take anything after the context root up to the first `/` exclusive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Don't i need the backslash for the dot? And customer1 was an example. In practice it will be "toto", "customer1", "xyz", ... But that with localhost is actualy a test. What's the difference between jboss rewrite valwer and UrlRewriterFilter? Thank you for the log tip. I'll try that this evening.

Comment: If customer1 is an example, what are the other examples? Or better - what are the general rules you want to express using `RewriteRule`s?

Comment: The difference against UrlRewriterFilter - well it's a different implementation, so what doesn't work in one might work with the other... But generally I'd rather bet on the JBoss one.

Comment: examples are : https://localhost:8443/test/john/login.xhtml, https://localhost:8443/test/mike/login.xhtml, .. sorry, unfortunately i still had no time to test that. Maybe this evening or tomorrow! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Ah, I get it now. I thought that you want to split the string "customer1" to "customer" and "1" :)  Ok in that case, it's simpler - I'd try removing the `$` and limit the characters instead using `([A-Za-z0-9]+)`, or `([^/]+)`, or other class definition.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `RewriteLog` directive to see what's happening.

Looking at your rewrite rule, though, I have a hunch I know what's wrong:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$/login\.xhtml /login.xhtml?customer=$1
```

First, this rule shouldn't match because of the `$` in the middle of the string - that should mark the end of the request string. Everything after that is extraneous. Let's take that out:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/login\.xhtml /login.xhtml?customer=$1
```

If I apply this rule to `https://localhost:8443/test/customer1/login.xhtml`, I will be redirected to `https://localhost:8443/login.xhtml?customer=test/customer1`, which is not what you wanted. My guess is that you need to account for the `/test/` part of the path. To get the output you wanted, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)/login\.xhtml /test/login.xhtml?customer=$1
```

Comment: very interesting, i'll test that as soon as possible!! I thought the '$' was necessery to be able to use the $1 in the second part. thanks

Comment: Yeah, the `$` is an anchor for the right side. It's the parens `()` that let you use `$1` in the second part.